# Getting "TCP Provider: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it" error when querying SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, laravel

I'm encountering an error while trying to connect to a SQL Server database using the ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server. When I execute a simple query like `select * from sysobjects where type = 'U' and name = migrations`, I receive the following error message:

> SQLSTATE[08001]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]TCP Provider: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.

I've checked my connection string, and it seems to be correct. I've also verified that the SQL Server instance is up and running. Despite this, I'm still unable to establish a connection.

Here's the connection string I'm using laravel:

```
DB_CONNECTION=sqlsrv
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=1433
DB_DATABASE=test;
DB_USERNAME=test
DB_PASSWORD=test@123
```

Comment: Are you trying to connect to an SQL Server Express instance by chance? Out of the box Express edition rarely has the TCP/IP server protocol enabled and, even when it does, it's usually listening on a random dynamic port (i.e.: not tcp/1433).